# How to notification on ios device with nativescript?

Tags: ios, notifications, nativescript

I coding mobile application with nativescript and use plugin `nativescript-local-notifications` to notification in my application but its work only on android and IOS Emulator.
I running my application on ios device and its not notifications anything to me.
How to fixing its?

Comment: You need to ask for permission to be able to send notifications on iOS - have you done so?  https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-local-notifications#requestpermission

Comment: Permission is true but its can not notification on device ios